# Find the triangle area AYE

Tags: geometry, area

Triangle ABC has area 60 cm^2.Let AD be the median from A on BC and BY be median from B on AD. If BY is extended to meet AC in E what is the area of triangle AYE?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Menelaus' theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MenelausTheorem.html), we have
$$\frac{CB}{BD}\cdot\frac{DY}{YA}\cdot \frac{AE}{EC}=1\iff CE:EA=2:1.$$

Hence, the answer is
$$60\times \frac{CD}{CB}\times\frac{EA}{CA}\times \frac{AY}{AD}=60\times\frac 12\times\frac 13\times\frac 12=5\ (\text{cm}^2).$$

Comment: Sorry can you explain it to me without vector method... Please

Comment: @user2131465: Sure. Take a look. I hope this helps.

Comment: No, I still don't get it. I am unaware of the above theorem, I read it but I still don't get the second part, where we have CD/CB.

Comment: @user2131465: OK, let me expalin a bit. $60=ABC$ (here $ABC$ means the area of the triangle $ABC$.) and $60\times (CD/CB)=ADC$. And $ADC\times (EA/CA)=AED$. And $AED\times (AY/AD)=AYE$, which is what we need.

Comment: @user2131465: Isn't my comment helpful?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Menelaus theorem made easy]

Since any affine map preserves the ratio between the areas, you are free to assume that the triangle $ABC$ has a right angle in $B$, and 
$$ A=(0,0),\quad B=(0,1),\quad C=(1,1),$$
hence:
$$ D=(1,1/2),\qquad Y=(1/2,1/4).$$
Now it is not difficult to check that the $BY$ line meet the $AC$ line in the point $(1/3,1/3)$, hence:
$$[AYE]=\frac{1}{3}[AYC]=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}[ACD]=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}[ABC]=\frac{1}{12}[ABC]=5.$$